# Can access the Parse methods for a given type based on an instance of Type in C#?

Tags: c#, types, string-parsing

I'm using a `DataTable` and assigning columns different types. I have a scenario where I'm receiving `String` data and I want to parse it based on the column's assigned type, but I can't figure out how to get to the parse methods.

Is is it possible to access the Type instance's parse methods in a generic way?

Comment: Those are `static` methods; they have nothing to do with the `System.Type` instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx).

Comment: Wow, I couldn't have received a faster response if you were standing next to me! LOL That's awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using anything more than basic types (that `Convert.ChangeType` handles quite nicely), the preferred way of doing this is via the `TypeConverter`:

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
object val = converter.ConvertFromString(s); // note various overloads,
                                             // or ConvertFromInvariantString
```

This is convenient because this model can be extended to recognise additional types (or change the implementation for existing types), both at compile-time (adding `[TypeConverter(...)]`) or at run-time (`TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(...)`).